# jquery use input box content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calling the ion.rangeslider jquery snippet like this...

```
$("#rangeSlider").ionRangeSlider({
    grid: true,
    from: +moment(today).format("X"),
    step: 86400,
});
```

I am trying to replace 'from:' with the value of an input box like this...

```
$("#rangeSlider").ionRangeSlider({
    grid: true,
    from: jQuery( '.price_from').val(),
    step: 86400,
});
```

But it's not working, I am pretty sure it is just a syntax issue

can anyone show me where am I going wrong?

Comment: is price_from your field id? Then you might wanna use ``#price_from``

Comment: No errors in the console, looking at the HTML source I can see that it is just printing from: jQuery( 'price_from').val(), instead of the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your selector is wrong.

It should be either

```
jQuery( '#price_from').val() // if price_from is an id
```

or

```
jQuery( '.price_from').val() // if price_from is a class
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting my obvious mistake!  However, even after correcting it still doesn't work.  I have updated the original post

Comment: What did you get if you command `jQuery( '.price_from')` in your browser console?

Comment: If I command jQuery( '.price_from') then I get the expected value

Comment: Did your input box really have a value when you use `jQuery( '.price_from').val()`? If it really had a value, then what do you get if you command `jQuery( '.price_from').val()` in the console?
This code should work if your selector is correct.